# ATG rest services

Tags: atg, servletconfig

I tried to create a rest service in atg with following urls

```
/services/v1/PassbookActor/Create,\
/services/v1/PassbookActor/Register
```

I'm using advanced rest client to run the webservices.
When i execute create url, I'm getting the output correctly and also changes are visible in acc. But when i try to execture register url, changes are visible in acc but i'm getting error 500 illegal state exception.

```
11:21:07,998 ERROR [nucleusNamespace.atg.dynamo.servlet.dafpipeline.ActorServlet] (http-/127.0.0.1:8180-2) Error code: 500
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ServletConfig has not been initialized
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getInitParameterNames(GenericServlet.java:163) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Fina
l-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
        at atg.beans.BeanPropertyMapper.getPropertyValue(BeanPropertyMapper.java:183) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.beans.DynamicBeans.getPropertyValue(DynamicBeans.java:402) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.service.filter.bean.BeanFilterImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanFilterImpl.java:150) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.service.filter.bean.BeanFilterRegistryImpl.doApplyFilter(BeanFilterRegistryImpl.java:651) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.
jar:]
        at atg.service.filter.bean.BeanFilterRegistryImpl.doApplyFilter(BeanFilterRegistryImpl.java:675) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.
jar:]
        at atg.service.filter.bean.BeanFilterRegistryImpl.doApplyFilter(BeanFilterRegistryImpl.java:675) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.
jar:]
        at atg.service.filter.bean.BeanFilterRegistryImpl.applyFilter(BeanFilterRegistryImpl.java:425) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.ja
r:]
        at atg.service.filter.bean.BeanFilterRegistryImpl.applyFilter(BeanFilterRegistryImpl.java:396) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.ja
r:]
        at atg.rest.RestActorManager.processActor(RestActorManager.java:252) [_REST_slib_satg-rest-1.0.jar:]
        at atg.rest.processor.ActorProcessor.handleRequest(ActorProcessor.java:202) [_REST_slib_satg-rest-1.0.jar:]
        at atg.rest.processor.ActorProcessor.doRESTPost(ActorProcessor.java:150) [_REST_slib_satg-rest-1.0.jar:]
        at atg.rest.servlet.RestPipelineServlet.serviceRESTRequest(RestPipelineServlet.java:477) [_REST_slib_satg-rest-1.0.ja
r:]
        at atg.rest.servlet.RestPipelineServlet.service(RestPipelineServlet.java:274) [_REST_slib_satg-rest-1.0.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.service(PipelineableServletImpl.java:320) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.rest.servlet.RestPipelineServlet.service(RestPipelineServlet.java:252) [_REST_slib_satg-rest-1.0.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.service(PipelineableServletImpl.java:320) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.rest.servlet.RestPipelineServlet.service(RestPipelineServlet.java:252) [_REST_slib_satg-rest-1.0.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.service(PipelineableServletImpl.java:320) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.rest.servlet.RestPipelineServlet.service(RestPipelineServlet.java:252) [_REST_slib_satg-rest-1.0.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.service(PipelineableServletImpl.java:320) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.rest.servlet.RestPipelineServlet.service(RestPipelineServlet.java:278) [_REST_slib_satg-rest-1.0.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.service(PipelineableServletImpl.java:320) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.rest.servlet.RestPipelineServlet.service(RestPipelineServlet.java:278) [_REST_slib_satg-rest-1.0.jar:]
        at atg.rest.servlet.HeadRestServlet.service(HeadRestServlet.java:141) [_REST_slib_satg-rest-1.0.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.service(PipelineableServletImpl.java:267) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.rest.servlet.RestProxyServlet.service(RestProxyServlet.java:139) [_REST_slib_satg-rest-1.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.7.
Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-re
dhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at atg.service.configuration.ResponseWrappingConfiguration.invokeFilterChainWithPossibleWrapping(ResponseWrappingConf
iguration.java:460) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.TailPipelineServlet.service(TailPipelineServlet.java:174) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.DispatcherPipelineServletImpl.service(DispatcherPipelineServletImpl.java:275) [_DAS_slib_scla
sses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.endeca.assembler.AssemblerPipelineServlet.service(AssemblerPipelineServlet.java:472) [_DAF.Endeca.Assembler_sl
ib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.servlet.http.CookieBufferServlet.service(CookieBufferServlet.java:119) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.userprofiling.ExpiredPasswordServlet.service(ExpiredPasswordServlet.java:383) [_DPS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.MimeTyperPipelineServlet.service(MimeTyperPipelineServlet.java:228) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]

        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.droplet.DropletEventServlet.service(DropletEventServlet.java:696) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.commerce.order.CommerceCommandServlet.service(CommerceCommandServlet.java:150) [_DCS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.commerce.promotion.PromotionServlet.service(PromotionServlet.java:213) [_DCS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.userprofiling.AccessControlServlet.service(AccessControlServlet.java:728) [_DPS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.servlet.sessionsaver.SessionSaverServlet.service(SessionSaverServlet.java:2452) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.userprofiling.PageEventTriggerPipelineServlet.service(PageEventTriggerPipelineServlet.java:191) [_DPS_slib_scl
asses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.endeca.clickthrough.servlet.SearchClickThroughServlet.service(SearchClickThroughServlet.java:454) [_DAF.Endeca
.Assembler_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.multisite.SiteSessionEventTriggerPipelineServlet.service(SiteSessionEventTriggerPipelineServlet.java:161) [_DA
S_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.userprofiling.SessionEventTrigger.service(SessionEventTrigger.java:512) [_DPS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.userprofiling.ProfilePropertyServlet.service(ProfilePropertyServlet.java:230) [_DPS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.userprofiling.ProfileRequestServlet.service(ProfileRequestServlet.java:461) [_DPS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.projects.store.servlet.pipeline.ProtocolSwitchServlet.service(ProtocolSwitchServlet.java:311) [_Store.EStore_s
lib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.DynamoPipelineServlet.service(DynamoPipelineServlet.java:491) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.URLArgumentPipelineServlet.service(URLArgumentPipelineServlet.java:298) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.j
ar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PathAuthenticationPipelineServlet.service(PathAuthenticationPipelineServlet.java:392) [_DAS_s
lib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.servlet.security.ThreadUserBinderServlet.service(ThreadUserBinderServlet.java:113) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.dtm.TransactionPipelineServlet.service(TransactionPipelineServlet.java:234) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.SecurityServlet.service(SecurityServlet.java:200) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.multisite.SiteContextPipelineServlet.service(SiteContextPipelineServlet.java:515) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar
:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.HeadPipelineServlet.passRequest(HeadPipelineServlet.java:1294) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.HeadPipelineServlet.service(HeadPipelineServlet.java:963) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.service(PipelineableServletImpl.java:272) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.filter.dspjsp.PageFilter.innerDoFilter(PageFilter.java:348) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at atg.filter.dspjsp.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:206) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.
Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-re
dhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1
.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1
.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-
as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7
.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.
5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.j
ar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5
.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.
7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.F
inal-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.F
inal-redhat-1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
```

Comment: I'm using atg 11.2, jboss-eap-6.4

Comment: On the assumption that you have included the OOTB REST module have you configured the access for your custom web services in the `ActorChainRegistry`?  Look in the component browser in dyn/admin or the ACC for `/atg/rest/userprofiling/` there are a number of Access related components on this path that you need to configure for your custom components.